# Is it possible to predict using a single variable in multiple regression?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis

In linear regression created using more than one training data, I have to predict using only one variable.

One possible scenario results as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = [[0, 1], [5, 1], [15, 2], [25, 5], [35, 11], [45, 15], [55, 34], [60, 35]]
y = [4, 5, 20, 14, 32, 22, 38, 43]
x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)

model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

test_x = np.array([5, 20, 14, 32, 22, 38])
model.predict(test_x.reshape(-1,1))
```

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Test_x set should be something like x array, You have two features and trying to test with 1 feature.

Comment: @MhDG7 But here you used 2 variables. x1: 5,14,22 x2: 20,32,38 Let's say you have created a model that estimates the number of sales using vehicle price and horsepower. Then we want to make estimates using only horsepower without price information.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Perhaps you can zeros to the second columns.

Comment: Is it possible to show the results in a two-dimensional scatter plot? @Grayrigel

Comment: Yes. If you mean predicted vs original  values.

Comment: in this case, the test data will consist of a nx2 matrix i.e. x1 and x2. the predicted results are one dimensional (y_pred). So do I need to show just one of x1 or x2 on the chart? Or is there a special case? @Grayrigel

Comment: Ideally, you compare y_pred, y_test (x1 dimensional). You don't compare y_pred and x_test. So, you can show y_test on X and y_pred on Y axis or vice versa

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve here. It is close to what is called marginal means, implemented in R and stata. In your scenario, you can just set the first variable at its mean to evaluate the second variable

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Each observation in your features matrix is composed of 2 values (for 2 features). You were trying to pass 6 values at once, instead of separating those 6 values into 3 array each consisting of 2 values (representing an observation in your data).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = [[0, 1], [5, 1], [15, 2], [25, 5], [35, 11], [45, 15], [55, 34], [60, 35]]
y = [4, 5, 20, 14, 32, 22, 38, 43]
x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)

model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

test_x = np.array([[5, 20], [14, 32], [22, 38]])
model.predict(test_x)
```

I can suggest two methods for your desired approach:

1. You can use a zero value for columns you do not wish to make use of when predicting an output.
2. You may train the model on the desired features.

```
"""create dummy data"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# construct a few features
features = np.array([[2, 2],
                     [4, 6],
                     [9, 1],
                     [6, 2]])

# construct a target
target = np.array([15, 20, 50, 18])

# construct a dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

dataframe['Price'] = features[:, 0]

dataframe['HorsePower'] = features[:, 1]

dataframe['Cost'] = target

# p.s. I've used the long method to construct my dataframe, you may pass data using the 'data' parameter.
print(dataframe)
print(' ')

# separate features matrix and target vector
features = dataframe.iloc[:, 0:2]
target = dataframe.iloc[:, -1]

# import package
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# create instance of LR
algorithm = LinearRegression()

# train the model on both features
model = algorithm.fit(features, target)

# view parameters and hyperparameters
print(model)

# create observation passing values for both features
observation = [[9, 1]]

# obtain predictions
predictions = model.predict(observation)

# print prediction
print(predictions)

plt.scatter(dataframe.index, target, color='crimson', marker='v', edgecolors='black', label='Target_Value')
plt.scatter(dataframe.index, model.predict(features), color='silver', marker='d', edgecolors='black', label='Predicted_Value')
plt.title('Scatter Plot Showing Predicted Target Values Vs Actual Target Values', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Observation Number', color='blue')
plt.ylabel('Value', color='blue')
plt.legend(numpoints=1, loc='best')
plt.show()

# train model, this time on desired feature (s)
model = algorithm.fit(np.array(features.iloc[:, 0]).reshape(-1, 1), 
    target)

# obtain prediction
prediction = model.predict([[2]])

# print predictions
print(prediction)
```

Comment: But here you used 2 variables.
x1: 5,14,22
x2: 20,32,38

Let's say you have created a model that estimates the number of sales using vehicle price and horsepower. Then we want to make estimates using only horsepower without price information.

Comment: @UğurEren, what do you mean?

Comment: The only aspect I have changed is the test_x array.

Comment: From my experience with Linear Regression, I have always provided an input for columns I used in order to train the model.

Comment: So how would you show the results in a two-dimensional graph?

Comment: results as in the predicted values? For the training on both columns, or one column?

Comment: With an N-dimensional test data and y_pred

Comment: You would most likely plot a graph that displays the actual target value vs the predicted target value.

Comment: You are most welcome @UğurEren. I do hope I was able to assist a little. :)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a linear regression is to find a linear relationship between input values and output values.

Basically it is : `y=θx+Ɛ` with `y` your prediction, `θ` the model parameters (fine tuned with training), `x` your input and `Ɛ` an error coefficient. The training purpose is to find the best `θ` and `Ɛ` to make your predictions as accurate as possible.

[To illustrate with a picture, θ and Ɛ are the red curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67I9Y.png)

You can not train a linear regression model with a certain dimension (input and output) and make predictions with another dimension :

in your example you talked about `[price, horsepower]`, a *(2,1)* matrix wich is `x` in the formula, to determine the price `y` wich is a *scalar*. So, `θ` should be a *(1,2)* matrix and `Ɛ` a *scalar*.

If you want to use price or horsepower only, you have to create a differents models for each sort of input.